# Can't open .prototxt and .caffemodel files

Tags: python, python-3.x, caffe, opencv

I am trying this code to detect age and gender using youtube video but it is unable to read .protxt and .caffemodel files.

```
import pafy
import cv2
import numpy as np
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cQ54GDm1eL0'
vPafy = pafy.new(url)
play = vPafy.getbest(preftype="mp4")

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(play.url)
cap.set(3, 480) #set width of the frame
cap.set(4, 640) #set height of the frame

MODEL_MEAN_VALUES = (78.4263377603, 87.7689143744, 114.895847746)
age_list = ['(0, 2)', '(4, 6)', '(8, 12)', '(15, 20)', '(25, 32)', '(38, 43)', '(48, 53)', '(60, 100)']
gender_list = ['Male', 'Female']

def load_caffe_models():

  age_net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab/deploy_age.prototxt', '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab/age_net.caffemodel')
  gender_net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab/deploy_gender.prototxt', '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab/gender_net.caffemodel')
  return(age_net, gender_net)

def video_detector(age_net, gender_net):
  font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

if __name__ == "__main__":
  age_net, gender_net = load_caffe_models()
  video_detector(age_net, gender_net)
  cap.read()
```

I am getting following error:

> error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/dnn/src/caffe/caffe_io.cpp:1121: error: (-2:Unspecified error) FAILED: fs.is_open(). Can't open "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab/deploy_age.prototxt" in function 'ReadProtoFromTextFile'

Comment: What error it is giving? post your full error trace?

Comment: error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/dnn/src/caffe/caffe_io.cpp:1121: error: (-2:Unspecified error) FAILED: fs.is_open(). Can't open "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab/deploy_age.prototxt" in function 'ReadProtoFromTextFile'

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that there is no such a file in the directory `'/content/drive/My Drive/Colab/deploy_age.prototxt'`.

Please make sure that it is available in that directory.

Thank you!